# Rearranging Order of Aligned Objects For Minimal Space Usage

Tags: c, gcc, x86, ld, memory-alignment

I have a data structure that needs to be 4-KiB aligned. I can enforce this using `__attribute__ ((aligned (4096)))`.

The problem is that this alignment requirement causes memory to be wasted. This is how the linker places the symbols (`pg_dir` is the aligned data structure):

```
00011000 <cursor_loc>:
00012000 <pg_dir>:
00013000 <idt>:
```

`cursor_loc` is just four bytes in size. This would be better:

```
00011000 <pg_dir>:
00012000 <cursor_loc>:
00012008 <idt>:
```

(`idt` must be 8-byte aligned here.)

---

You can reproduce it by using multiple files like this:

`test1.c`:

```
char aligned[4096] __attribute__ ((aligned (4096)));
int i;
```

`test2.c`:

```
int j;

int main(void) { }
```

Then build it with

```
gcc test1.c test2.c
```

and `objdump -D a.out` prints this:

```
0000000000602004 <j>:
        ...

0000000000603000 <aligned>:
        ...

0000000000604000 <i>:
```

---

How can I move GNU ld to rearrange symbols for minimal space waste? I really wonder why it isn't done automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some idioms which require that objects are arranged in the order objects are specified on the command line (which is why your results are a bit odd, maybe it's due to common symbols), and that intra-object definitions are not reordered.  To work around that, you need something like this:

```
gcc -fno-common -fdata-sections -Wl,--sort-section=alignment test1.c test2.c
```

`-fno-common` disables common symbols, `-fdata-sections` allows the linker to reorder symbols from the same file, and `-Wl,--sort-section=alignment` finally enables sorting by alignment.

Comment: That works neatly, thanks. I just wonder why the symbols still appear to be in `.bss` when I `objdump` them, even though I use `-fno-common` and `-fdata-sections`. I need them to be in `.bss` for my purposes actually, it's just I don't understand why those switches don't change the section they belong to.

Comment: Yes, I was confused about `.bss`. You can only get zero-initialized symbols out of `.bss` if you specify an initializer, and if that is still zero, compile `-fno-zero-initialized-in-bss` (to inhibit the `.bss` optimization). Glad you need `.bss` symbols anyway.

Comment: I tried `-Wl,--sort-common`, but couldn't get the desired effect.